# Using CONCAT with / on a SELECT query MySQL 8

Tags: select, concatenation

I am trying to add a missing character to a partial subset of a column.

The correct format for the start of the column value is **AB1234-**
Some records are a missing the hyphen

I can find those records that are missing the hyphen by

`SELECT * FROM` electricals`WHERE`Partnumber`NOT REGEXP '^.{6}[-]'  AND`Partnumber `REGEXP '^AB1234' ;`

And I have found an idea to add the missing hyphen as follows

`SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTR(`Partnumber`, 1 , 6), '-', )`

But I don't know how to get both to work together (novice MySQL)

Hope you can help, thanks

Tried various attempts to run them together incl. a subquery, but syntax always failed :(

I'm probably missing something very basic...